# pass a function pointer between classes

Tags: c++

I have two claces.
here is the first one

```
class one{
    one(){ }
  public:
    void change(double a){
       //print a
    }

    void run(){
     two tw;
     tw->functionpointer=&change;
   }

};
```

and here is the `two` class

```
public two{

   two();

   static void progresschange(double v){
      functionpointer(v);
   }

   public:
     void (*functionpointer)(double);
 };
```

as you see in example I have a function in class one, I want to call it from an static function in class two As `progresschange` is static I can only call `change` function in class one uisng function pointers. but It does not work and compiles says

```
 error: cannot convert ‘void (one::*)(double)’ to ‘void (*)(double)’ in assignment
```

it happens in this line

```
tw->functionpointer=&change;
```

how can I make it work. it is even possible to pass a function using its function pointer to another class using this method?
thanks

Comment: `std::function` to the rescue!

Comment: @Bathsheba can you explain a bit more, thanks

Comment: Please repeat after me: A pointer to a non-member function is *not* the same as a pointer to a member function.

Comment: A pointer to a non-member function is not the same as a pointer to a member function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks but how can I fix it?is not any way to call change in class two?

Comment: Also, for future questions please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Something which we can copy-paste and see the error for ourselves.

Comment: @MajidHojati yes, you can if you pass the object which `change()` will be called on.

Comment: As mentioned by @Bathsheba, [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) comes to mind. Please do some research about it, and possibly about [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) as well.

Comment: @水飲み鳥 thanks very much, but how?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, I tried to provide a minimal example, but forgot to verify it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can not use bind I think, I also tried to use std::function but again no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::function<void(double)>’ and ‘void (one::*)(double)’)

Comment: What about changing one of them so they match?

Comment: @super how?I did not get what you mean

Comment: one is of type `std::function<void(double)>` and the other is `void (one::*)(double)`. You decided to try to use std::function... so maybe you can change `functionpointer` to a `std::function<void(double)>` aswell?

Comment: @super if I can not change it?

Answer (score 4):

The error message is quite straightforward:

> error: cannot convert `void (one::*)(double)` to `void (*)(double)` in assignment

`void one::change(double)` is a *member function* of the class `one`, not just a function. Therefore, you can't assign a pointer to this member function (i.e.: `void (one::*)(double)`) to a *pointer to a function* with the same signature (i.e.: to a `void (*)(double)`).

Besides, a non-`static` member function (like `one::change()` above) has to be called on an object, so you also need to provide an `one` object to call that pointed-to non-`static` member function.

---

Basically, you can achieve what you want by adding the following data members in `two`:

```
void (one::*mem_func_ptr)(double);
one *obj_ptr;
```

That is, a *pointer to the member function* (`mem_func_ptr`) and a *pointer to the object to call this member function on* (`obj_ptr`).
To assign to the member function pointer:

```
mem_func_ptr = &one::change;
```

Then, to call the member function pointed by `mem_func_ptr` on the object pointed by `obj_ptr` with `0.0` as argument:

```
(obj_ptr->*mem_func_ptr)(0.0);
```

It can be done analogously by keeping a copy of an object `one` as data member instead of a ponter. In that case you should use the operator `.*` instead of `->*`.

Comment: Nice, but in absolute honesty, member function syntax really isn't "straightforward"

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `one::change()` is a class member so you need to pass a pointer to a class instance as well.

The modern way to do it is to use `std::function`, `std::bind` and `std::mem_fn`:

```
class two {
....
  std::function<void(double)> functionpointer;
}


tw->functionpointer = std::bind(std::mem_fn(&one::change), _1, one_instance);
```

Alternatively you can use a lambda function:

```
tw->functionpointer = [&one_instance](double x) { one_instance->change(x); }
```

Comment: thanks but I faced errors in both methods, tw->functionpointer = std::bind(std::mem_fn(&one::change), _1, one_instance); and tw->functionpointer = [&one_instance](double x) { one_instance->change(x); } both gives me errors. I just passed this instead of one_instance what is _1 in first method?

Comment: Yes, replace one_instance with some instance of the class one. this works just fine if you are in a method of the class one. _1 is a way to tell bind the the parameter goes in the first position. This is to allow  you to reorder parameters or to substitute some arbitrary parameter. Check the documentation for more details. Also if you want help with the errors please post the message.

Comment: thanks, I fixed my problem with _1 but it says  cannot convert ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, std::_Mem_fn<void (one::*)(double)>, const std::_Placeholder<1>&, one*>::type {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (one::*)(double)>(std::_Placeholder<1>, one*)>}’ to ‘void (*)(double)’ in assignment

                                                                                                   ^